# ScriptManager in DotNetNuke 6

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke

When I call the

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(string),"Something","document.getElementById('xxx').style.display='inline'",true)
```

in a custom DNN module and having partial rendering enabled on my control, the code does not work. However, when I remove the panels from the ascx and disable the partial render it works. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I've had luck using the overload that takes a `Page` instead of a `Control` (i.e. change the first argument from `Me` to `Me.Page`)

Answer (score 0):

Put your function in a JS file, or inject it onto the page so it always exists, then try this function (you could remove the stringbuilder, it was used when developing the function):

IncludeAJAXEndRequest(ctrl, "YourJSFunction")
ctrl is some control on your page, maybe a placeholder

```
    public void IncludeAJAXEndRequest(Control c, string s)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();\n" +
            "if (prm)\n" +
            "\tprm.add_endRequest({0});\n", s);
        IncludeScript(c, true, sb.ToString());
    }
```